# Updating a Two Dimensional Dataframe Python with a Multiindex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a heatmap with some data. For this I've created an empty bidimensional dataframe

`dft = pd.DataFrame(0, index=matrix_values_index , columns= matrix_values_columns)`

Which gives me a 58x58 matrix.

[image: Bidimensional dataframe]

On the other hand, there are some data within an excel spreadsheet which I've transformed into a multiindex dataframe

`df2 = heatmap_values.groupby(['ID Requester','ID Supplier']).agg({'ID Supplier':'count'})`

`df2.rename(columns={'ID Supplier': 'No. Interdependencies'})`

The first index is the index of the bidimensional dataframe

The second index is the column of the bidimensional dataframe

[image: This is the multiindex data frame]

Is there a way to update the bidimensional dataframe with the values of the multiindex dataframe without looping over it?

I've been looking for a solution for it all over the internet, but without success so far.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if some index or columns names missing instead your solution:

```
dft = (pd.crosstab(heatmap_values['ID Requester'],heatmap_values['ID Supplier'])
         .reindex(index=matrix_values_index, columns= matrix_values_columns, fill_value=0))
```

Your solution should be changed for same ouput with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and also `reindex`:

```
df2 = heatmap_values.groupby(['ID Requester','ID Supplier']).agg({'ID Supplier':'count'})

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'ID Supplier': 'No. Interdependencies'})

dft = (df2['No. Interdependencies'].unstack(fill_value=0)
                                   .reindex(index=matrix_values_index,
                                            columns= matrix_values_columns, 
                                            fill_value=0))
```

Comment: I'm trying your approach but not it's not working. I've replaced the (df['ID Requester'],df['ID Supplier']) by (df2.index.names[0],df2.index.names[1]) since it is a Multiindex dataframe, but without success so far

Comment: @Nikolas - Added your solution to my answer.

Comment: Hello @jezrael I've used some of your tips and finally succeded: 

dfn = df2.unstack()
dfn_reduced = dfn.xs('ID IPM Supplier', axis=1, drop_level=True).fillna(0) 
dfn_full = dfn_reduced.reindex(index=matrix_values_index , columns= matrix_values_columns, fill_value=0) –

Comment: @Nikolas - So data are different like `df2 = heatmap_values.groupby(['ID Requester','ID Supplier']).agg({'ID Supplier':'count'})

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'ID Supplier': 'No. Interdependencies'})`, so not possible use `df2['No. Interdependencies'].unstack(fill_value=0)` instead `dfn = df2.unstack() dfn_reduced = dfn.xs('ID IPM Supplier', axis=1, drop_level=True).fillna(0)` ?